# bxSlider – Active Thumbnail Opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

I am using the bx slider (http://bxslider.com/) and have customized it exactly as I want. I made the thumbnails 50% opacity and then 100% opacity on hover.

What I want to do now is to make the "active" thumbnail 100% opacity as well. The plugin adds a class called "active" to the active thumbnail, but when I try to simply add a line in the css to change the opacity of ".active" to 100%, it doesn't work. Why?

Test site: http://patrickmauldin.com/testingserver/kerri/

Custom jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
    mode: 'fade',
    controls: false,
    auto: true
  });
});
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try this in css : #bx-pager a.active { opacity :1 !important}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this code: (`.active a`  to  `#bx-pager a.active`)

```
.active a{ opacity: 1 }
```

to

```
#bx-pager a.active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Totally didn't think about using "!important"

Answer (score 0):

The opacity is being overwritten by:

```
#bx-pager a
{
    margin-right: 17px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

because it is more specific than just `.active { opacity: 1; }`. One way to solve this problem is to add `!important` like so:

```
.active
{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

if for some reason you don't want to use `!important` you can increase the specificity as well:

```
#bx-pager .active
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```